# Spring Data Pagination GroupBy

Tags: spring-boot, group-by, pagination, spring-data

I need the solution for the below question using Spring Data / Spring Boot.

I have a record in my MySQL table which is something like:

```
---------------------------------
| id  | Postcontent | postdate  |
------+-------------+------------
| 1   |  A          | 2013-01-31|
| 2   |  B          | 2013-01-31|
| 3   |  C          | 2013-01-30|
| 4   |  D          | 2013-01-30|
| 5   |  E          | 2013-01-29|
| 6   |  F          | 2013-01-29|
```

and I would like to show it in something like

2013-01-31

A

B

2013-01-30

C

D

2013-01-29

E

F

i can able to show like above with group by, but not able to add pagination in group by

if anyone can help me on how to add pagination in group by.

Comment: It would be clear to answer if you put your sample code here. Assuming you are using `spring data repository` method to achieve this then you can simply add Pageable as a parameter to the method and return type should be `Page<yourClass>`.